# Некорректное повидение ListView

Tags: java, android, listview

Есть ListView , в котором наблюдается странное поведение. В адаптер передается список из 38 элементов. Проблемы:

1. Отображаются не все элементы а только часть.
2. Те элементы что отображаются - отображаются по кругу(при скороле), то есть на экране к примеру 8 элементов отображается, и нижний элемент проскролить до самого верху - когда он полностью скроется то снова появляется снизу.

**Adapter.java**

```
    public class ContactListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private static final String TAG = "ContactListAdapter";

    ArrayList<String> list;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    private ViewHolder preHolder;
    private ViewHolder secondHold;



    public ContactListAdapter(Context context, List list) {
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list ;
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public static class ViewHolder {
        private View rootView;
        private TextView tvName;
        private TextView tvInitials;
        private ImageView ivAvatart;
        private ImageView ivStatus;

        private RelativeLayout relativeLayoutParent;
        private RelativeLayout relativeLayoutMain;
        private RelativeLayout onlineButtonContainer;
        private RelativeLayout timeoutButtonContainer;
        private RelativeLayout relativeLayout_exit_buuton_conteiner;
        private RelativeLayout relativeLayout_icon_phone;
        private String contactName;
        private boolean isShow;

    }


    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {

        final ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.rootView = convertView;
            holder.itemName = getItem(position);
            holder.contactName = holder.contactCaling.getDisplayName();


            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            holder.rootView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.main_contact_list_item, null);


            holder.tvName = (TextView) holder.rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView_contact_name);
            holder.tvInitials = (TextView) holder.rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView_contact_initials);
            holder.ivAvatart = (ImageView) holder.rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView_contact_avatar);
            holder.ivStatus = (ImageView) holder.rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView_status);

            holder.relativeLayoutParent = (RelativeLayout) holder.rootView.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout_parent);
            holder.relativeLayoutMain = (RelativeLayout) holder.rootView.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout_main);
            holder.onlineButtonContainer = (RelativeLayout) holder.rootView.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout_call_button_container);
            holder.relativeLayout_icon_phone = (RelativeLayout)holder.rootView.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout_icon_phone);
            holder.timeoutButtonContainer = (RelativeLayout) holder.rootView.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout_call_busy_button_container);
            holder.relativeLayout_exit_buuton_conteiner = (RelativeLayout) holder.rootView.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout_exit_buuton_conteiner);

            holder.tvName.setText(holder.contactName);


            holder.rootView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        return holder.rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }


}
```

**listView.xml**

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView_contacts"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/relativeLayout_companies"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp">

</ListView>
```

Comment: ListView устарел и переиспользование элементов в нём (паттерн ViewHolder) реализуется сложно и непонятно. Настолько сложно и непонятно, что проще вникнуть в суть RecyclerView и использовать его взамен. А по вопросу... Вы текст назначаете только его holder null. посробуйте назначать его и в ином случае.

Comment: Да, вы уже не первый раз это советуете и я начал его использовать)  просто конкретно в этом месте был ListView.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Описывайте Холдер **за пределами** условия:

```
if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.rootView = convertView;

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

   holder.itemName = getItem(position);
   holder.contactName = holder.contactCaling.getDisplayName();
...
```

иначе он задается лишь 1 раз и только при первом показе

Comment: Спасибо, я все не мог понять почему такое странное поведение.